# remove NaN from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tried couple of things with no success.

The idea is to grap the value from the form and push to an array and add it all ...

the pageNext() function is supposed to just page through the form, hiding the previous and showing the next, and on the last page the idea is to have the submitBtn show something.

but for some reason, I am getting NaN pushed to the array, so I am trying to find a way to filter those NaN from my array? or not get them in the first place?

Appreciate.

```js
$(document).ready(init);
var answersTotal = [];
var answer;

function init(){
 $('#nextBtn').on('click', pageNext);
}



function grabAnswer(){
 answers = $("select option:selected");
 values = $.map(answers ,function(option) {
    return parseInt(option.value);
 });
 answersTotal.push(values);

 // answersTotal = answersTotal.filter(function(n){ return n != NaN });
 // console.log('answersTotal after filter: ', answersTotal);

}


function pageNext(){
 $('#nextBtn').on('click', function(){
  grabAnswer();
  console.log('values: ', values);
  
  console.log(answersTotal);
  $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
  if ($('.current').hasClass('last')){
   $('#nextBtn').hide();
   $('#submitBtn').show();
  };
 });
};
```

```css
.select2, .select3, .select4, .select5 {
 display: none;
}

#submitBtn {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field first current select1">
      <p>Q1?</p>
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">a</option>
          <option value="2">b</option>
          <option value="3">c</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field select2">
       <p>q2</p>
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="2">a</option>
          <option value="5">b</option>
          <option value="7">c</option>
          <option value="10">d</option>
          <option value="12">e</option>
        </select>
        <!-- <label>Materialize Select</label> -->
      </div>
      <div class="input-field select3">
       <p>What do you Find More Interesting?</p>
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>a</option>
          <option value="1">b</option>
          <option value="3">c</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: You could check for `Number.isNaN` in the filter rather than just blindly parsing

Comment: I'm guessing this only happens when the user doesn't select anything in the dropdowns. A simple solution would be to just set the value to `0` for the first default options

Comment: Yeah, that would do the trick. for some reason my form is jumping when you click the button, not allowing the user to answer all questions.

Comment: it's happening because `parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN`, fyi

Comment: so perhaps I should do my parseInt down the road?

Comment: `return Number.isNaN(parseInt(option.value)) ? 0 : parseInt(option.value);` if you really want to do the parse int there

Answer (score 22):

The simples way to remove NaNs from any array is to use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter) + [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN):

```
const newArray = oldArray.filter(function (value) {
    return !Number.isNaN(value);
});
```

Comment: Or in ES6: `const newArray = oldArray.filter( value => !Number.isNaN(value) );`